# TelecomManager: An exception on AddNewIncomingCall()

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, telecom-manager, telecom

I am trying to use Telecom features in my Xamarin.Forms app. When AddNewIncomingCall() is called, an exception is thrown:

> Java.Lang.SecurityException: Package com.android.phone does not belong to 10134

Here is the code:

```
        Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {            
            TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(TelecomService);

            // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android
            PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<ReadPhoneStatePermission>();
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<ReadPhoneStatePermission>();
            }

            PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle = telecomManager.CallCapablePhoneAccounts.FirstOrDefault();
            
            telecomManager.AddNewIncomingCall(phoneAccountHandle, new Bundle());
        });
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I **think** this is a package visibility issue - https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility

Comment: @Jason Thank you. But this article says it is about Android 11, but I now run an Android 10 - API 29 emulator.

Comment: @Json I still added   <queries>
    <package android:name="com.android.phone" />
  </queries> to manifest, but it did not help...

Comment: @DavidShochet Have you add the permission for `INTERNET` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Yes, I have.